# Parsing NSArray in Swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, nsarray

I am trying to parse a JSON file. The first level works fine, but when I want to get a step deeper, it doesn't work any more.

```
if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: ReceivedData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary {
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        let tokensLeft = json["tokensLeft"]

        print("Tokens Left")
        print(tokensLeft)

        let product = json["products"]

        print(product)

        for i in 0 ..< (product as AnyObject).count {
            let asin = product[i]["asin"] as? [[String:AnyObject]]
        }
    })
}
```

When I try it like this, I get this error at assigning a value to asin:
"Type 'Any?' has no subscript members"

The value of print(product) looks like this:

[image]

I already tried several solutions provided here, but nothing worked. Could it be a problem with the data in the array?

I would be happy for every idea you can provide to help solving this issue.

Thanks, 
Alexander.

Comment: cast your products to [[String: AnyObject]] then iterate through it and do not cast key "asin" to [[String: AnyObject]]

Comment: Thanks a lot - this worked out fine!!

Comment: You're welcome. Try to avoid NSDictionary and NSArray and code in swift standards. :-) https://engineering.vokal.io/iOS/CodingStandards/Swift.md.html https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is to cast your array into an `[[String:Any]]`. Do it like this **and check the comments for explanations**:

```
if let productsDictionary = json["products"] as? [[String:Any]] {
    // By doing if let you make sure you have a value when you reach this point

    // Now you can start iterate, but do it like this
    if let asin = productsDictionary["asin"] as? String, let author = productsDictionary["author"] as? String, etc... {
        // Use asin, autoher etc in here. You have now made sure that these has valid values
    }

    // If you have values that can be nil, just do it like this
    let buyBoxSellerIdHistory = productsDictionary["buyBoxSellerIdHistory"] as? Int
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanations - I will keep that in mind and update my code.